# Rails: correct way to define a scope to be overridden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the gem discarded which adds a scope with_discarded on every model on which it is loaded on.  To write some code that works with any model I added with_discarded scope (via a class method) on all models in application_record that does nothing so that then it will get overridden in those models which include the module from the discarded gem.

However, rails now produces a warning:
`Creating scope :with_discarded. Overwriting existing method User.with_discarded` every time I load a class that overwrites the base method.  For completeness that's implemented just as:

```
  def self.with_discarded 
    all
  end
```

Now everything seems to be working fine, but I'm wondering what the correct way to do this would be and why I'm being warned.  Am I supposed to define it as a scope rather than a class method (EDIT: tried it still get the warning)?  Alternatively, is there a way to just filter this warning out of all my logs without loading a gem like Semantic Logger.  Problem is that this warning shows up every time my GoodJob Scheduler runs and is polluting my logs.

Comment: You could define an empty scope at the top-level instead of a method, though I'm not sure that avoids the warning.

Comment: Thanks but I tried it no luck.  Still generates the warning.  Maybe I'll just have to live with it but I'd have assumed this was a standard thing people would want to do (override a scope in some models).

Comment: It's more common that people do it inadvertently and wonder why everything is broken than on purpose, hence the warning. If you really want to work around this, you can always make an alternate method you call instead that maps to either that, or the `all` default depending on configuration. This could be as simple as `respond_to?(:with_discarded) ? with_discarded : all`

Comment: Ahh, I guess that makes sense.  Truth is I'm a little fuzzy about how methods are dispatched when a class method is invoked on a scope (it seems like it's different because I can call a method that's defined only on the scope as if it was defined on self...I know there is some method_missing magic here)...but I guess it all seems to work like I'd expect in this case.

Comment: Normal inheritance of methods isn't subject to these rules, but scope definition is, apparently, so you need to pick which flavour of discomfort you're the most comfortable with. If this is particularly irritating, maybe there's a way to get the gem itself to chill out on the warnings with some kind of flag, either existing or as a feature request. You might also be able to undefine the method using `undef` before loading the extension.

Comment: Your first response worked for me.  I just hadn't gone that way because I was a little uncomfortable with my lack of understanding....but after some testing I verified that everything ended up working the way I needed it to so it seems like I'm all good.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Might be worth writing up a quick answer with your conclusion to show how it's done which not only helps with retention, but might assist someone else in the same jam.

Comment: Yup, good idea. I wanted to give you the chance if you wanted the answer but Im happy to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So I followed @tadman's suggestion and just implemented a new method as follows

```
  def self.include_discarded
    respond_to?(:with_discarded) ? with_discarded : all
  end
```

This doesn't quite let me overload the original with_discarded scope in the sense that I had to switch all the uses to include_discarded but it has the same effect.  You could try and give the method the same name via metaprogramming but then you'll need a good way to run code in every subclass of ApplicationRecord.